# Unresolved name for Trait when specifying the Type (<Type as Trait>)

Tags: rust

I have a struct `Bar` that implements the `Foo` trait.

```
struct Bar;

trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) {
        print!("Foo");
    }
}

impl Foo for Bar {}
```

I also have `Print` trait that takes a `Kind` parameter. Both `Foo` and `Bar` implement `Print` with `Bar` as its `Kind`.

```
trait Print {
    type Kind;
    fn print(_: &Self::Kind);
}

impl Print for Bar {
    type Kind = Bar;
    fn print(_: &Bar) {
        println!("Bar");
    }
}

impl Print for Foo {
    type Kind = Bar;
    fn print(bar: &Bar) {
        bar.foo();
        Bar::print(bar);
    }
}
```

Finally, I want to print `Bar` using the different implementations.

```
fn main() {
    let b = Bar;
    Bar::print(&b);          // prints: Bar
    Foo::print(&b);          // prints: FooBar
    <Bar as Foo>::print(&b); // error
}
```

The code is also available in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d604e6966a0f9cadc4bce60b748d4dd0)

The two first calls to `print` works fine but the line `<Bar as Foo>::print(&b);` gives the following compilation error:

```
error[E0576]: cannot find method or associated constant `print` in trait `Foo`
  --> src/main.rs:35:19
   |
35 |     <Bar as Foo>::print(&b); // error
   |                   ^^^^^ not found in `Foo`
```

I would have expected the last two lines to print the same thing. Why do I get an error saying that `Foo::print` is an unresolved name, when the line above works fine? What's the difference between the two lines?

Comment: I would have expected Bar::print to error out due to ambiguity... Maybe you found a bug?

Comment: @ker: why? `Bar::print` is not ambiguous at all.

Comment: The associated types part of this question is completely a red herring.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Removed associated types from question now. Thanks

Comment: because the print function is available through Print on Bar and Print on Foo on Bar

Comment: @ker: “Print on Foo on Bar” is not a thing. `impl Print for Foo` is an implementation on the unsized type `Foo`—that is, `&self` is of type `&Foo`, a trait object. If one was to instead want to implement `Print` for all types that implement `Foo`, that would be `impl<T: Foo> Print for T`, and that would fail to compile due to trait coherence rules.

Comment: oooh... thanks, I was not aware of this distinction at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<A as B>` is [Fully Qualified Syntax (FQS)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name) meaning “find the implementation of the trait `B` for the type `A`”. Your `<Bar as Foo>::print`, then, is trying to call the `print` method from the `Foo` trait with `Bar` as `Self`. The `Foo` trait does not have any such method, and so it quite naturally fails. What you need there for that to work is `<Foo as Print>::print`.

`Bar::print` looks first for an intrinsic method on the type `Bar` and then for any method named `print` on any trait that `Bar` implements, and so is resolved as `<Bar as Print>::print`. The deal is the same for `Foo::Print`.